# The "Oh to have…" expression

Tags: meaning, etymology, expressions

What does "Oh to have..." mean, as in "Oh to have a song in a national campaign" in Jon Lajoie's song "[Please Use This Song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuQt9N4Dsok)"?

Can somebody explain the origin and meaning of this expression? In what contexts can it be used?

Comment: Can you give an example of this expression being used?

Comment: I asked myself this question when I heard :
"Oh to have a song in a national campaign" in "Please Use This Song" a song of JON LAJOIE.

Comment: I was wondering how to understand this sentence and more generally what was the origin of this expression that I find a bit weird in the construction (as a french).

Comment: I've added the example to the question and nominated it for reopening.

Comment: This is strictly **General Reference**, because this means exactly what the dictionary says it means. It is a standard word, used in a standard way. Please consult a dictionary for the interjection *oh* or *o*, which are the same thing.

Comment: @tchrist - This was closed as Unclear, by me among others, because the questioner didn't supply enough context. Now he has supplied the missing context, so it is no longer unclear. And there's much more in play here than just the word "oh"--what is your general reference cite for the "[interj], to [verb]" construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Richard III could have used the phrase rather than:

*"A horse, a horse, my kingdom for a horse!"*

For example:

*"Oh to have a horse!"*

It expresses a desperate desire to posses something that cannot be possessed.

Comment: Found more often in poetry.

Comment: I agree....it is not a conversational idiom.

Answer (score 1):

"Oh, to..." is a common poetic expression, indicating that the idea of something arouses the author's feelings.

***O, TO have** a little house!

To own the hearth and stool and all!*
- Padraic Colum

***O to go*** back to the place where I was born,
To hear the birds sing once more,
- Walt Whitman

***Oh, to be*** in England
Now that April's there,
- Robert Browwning

***Oh! to see** his tartan trews,

Bonnet blue, and laigh-heeled shoes,*
- Alexander Geddes

***Oh, to feel** the wild pulsation that in manhood’s dawn I knew,*
- William Edmondstoune Aytoun and Sir Theodore Martin

Answer (score 1):

The interjection *[oh](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/oh)* can have a number of meanings, one of which is to signal strong emotions.

When followed by an infinitive, it is often used to signal whistfulness or longing. This may be because the infinitive construction has a hypothetical characteristic, and the yearning expressed is for what could be rather than what is.

When the interjection is used to signal more immediate and pressing emotions, other forms are more common, such as simple nouns or imperative verbs

> Oh, the humanity! [expressing horror at the loss of life]
>
> Oh, please save me!
>
> Oh, go to hell!

Answer (score 0):

OED s.v. oh, *int.* and *n.<sup>1</sup>*

> A. *int.* Expressing (according to intonation) surprise, frustration, discomfort, longing, disappointment, sorrow, relief, hesitation, etc.

Here the expression is of longing. The relevant OED example is from the Hymns of Isaac Watts (1707): “Oh! could we make our doubts remove.” A closer parallel of the exact usage in question, with infinitive, though not explicitly mentioned in OED, is the opening line of Browning’s “Home Thoughts from Abroad” (1845): “Oh, to be in England now that April’s there.”